# How to overwrite bootstrap tooltip with mouse positions

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="#" class="spot ico_1 glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Dummy Text"></a>

$(".spot").mouseover(function(){
   var x = $(this).position();  
    var topval = x.top;
    var leftval = x.left;        
    $(this).attr("title", "X= "+topval+" "+"Y= "+leftval);      
});
```

How to overwrite bootstrap tooltip text with xy values from jquery? please help

Comment: can you create a demo in jsfiddle?

Comment: Well, all relevant details are in the event object you have available. Just use them how you like.